# Javascript: Stop until RETURN key is press

Tags: javascript, wait, keyevent

I'm newbie with javascript and I'm not able to figure out how to stop and wait until return key has been pressed.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You could either do it with a callback function, or using [`async` `await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) to wait a specific key is pressed:

```js
const keyIsPressed = target => new Promise(resolve => {
  document.body.addEventListener('keyup', ({ key }) => {
    if(key.toUpperCase() === target.toUpperCase()) {
      resolve();
    }
  }, { once: true });
});

async function start() {
  console.log('Waiting for user to press enter...');
  
  // pause here until enter is pressed
  await keyIsPressed('enter');
  
  console.log('Enter is pressed.');
}

start();
```

Comment: You might need to add `{once: true}` options or manually unsubscribe to avoid memory leak.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko You're absolutely right. Thanks for the correction.